# Excel VLOOKUP with multiple possible options in table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two lists, the first is a set of users. The second list contains different encounter dates for these users.

I need to identify the date that is within 10 days of the "Renew Date" [Column C], but not before. With Member 1 this would be row 3 1/8/2017. With Member 2 this would be row 6, 1/21/2017.

Now using a VLOOKUP which the user before me who managed this spreadsheet obviously isn't viable as it's simply going to pickup the first date that has a matching Member ID. Is there a way to do this in Excel at all?

I have included a link to a sample file and a screenshoit of the sample data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5kjsJZFrUgFcUFTNFBzQzN4cm8/view?usp=sharing

[image: Example Excel Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the slowness and complexities of array formulas, you can try with `SUMIFS` but the problem is that if you have more than one match, it will add them, not return the first match. The sum will look like an aberration. Will work however if you are guaranateed that you have only one match in the data.

An alternative is also to use `AVERAGEIFS`, which, in case of multiple matches, will give you their average and it will look like a valid date and a good result. Enter this formula in `D2` and fill down the column:

```
D2:
=AVERAGEIFS(G:G,F:F,A2,G:G,">="&C2,G:G,"<="&C2+10)
```

and don't forget to format column `D` as `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT($G$2:$G$7,--($F$2:$F$7=A2),--($G$2:$G$7<=C2+10),--($G$2:$G$7>C2))
```

Format the result as date. See screenshot (my system uses DMY order)

[image]

Don't use whole column references with this formula. It will slow down the workbook.